# Adding a space after a name.get

Tags: java

I am trying to add a question mark and a space after the name.get, but I cannot figure out how.

Can someone help me?

```
 System.out.print("What were the annual sales for " + name.get(0));
```

Comment: `+ name.get(0) + " ?");` ... ?

Comment: How did you add the second String to the first? Do that again.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank you, I was not properly adding the spacing after the +....its been a long day.

Comment: Yep, it's always the simple things ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just append a string with ?

```
System.out.print("What were the annual sales for " + name.get(0) + " ?");
```